# Azure Functions pruebas con azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure, function

Necesito ayuda para hacer las pruebas con azure functions en azure DevOps en el instante que hago un commit, utilice la guía de Microsoft para hacer las pruebas  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#c-in-visual-studio.
las pruebas ejecutan correctamente y subo el proyecto al repositorio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema surge en el momento de hacer los `pipelines`.
No sé cómo ejecutar las pruebas que hice en local, porque el repositorio no sube el proyecto de pruebas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por la falta de iconos que se visualizan en la imagen para ese proyecto de Test comparado con el otro proyecto, esta claro que el proyecto de test no esta integrado al repositorio de codigo.

[Share your code with Visual Studio 2017 and Azure Repos Git](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=vsts)

Si usas el `Team Explorer`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

conectado al `repo git` podrias subir el proyecto para tenerlo disponible en el control de codigo y que el pipeline pueda tomarlo desde alli y ejecutar los test

Comment: Es decir, sincronizo los dos proyectos (Function app y Function test)

Comment: a que llamas "sincronizo" ? tienes que integrarlo al repo de codigo que imagino realizas un commit, para despues que piepline tome de alli el codigo para compilar y ejcutar los test

Answer (score 0):

Si es un proyecto net.core lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera:

[image: ver]